# Playa broken in MySQL > 5.7.4

Tags: playa, pixelandtonic

Since v5.7.5 MySQL returns errors for certain badly formed SQL statements. As such Playa v4.5.2 will throw errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So far I've discovered and fixed one case and will add more here if discovered.

File: mod.playa.php
Line: 550

FROM

```
$sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT(rel.child_entry_id) AS entry_id
```

TO

```
$sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT rel.child_entry_id AS entry_id, rel.parent_entry_id, rel.parent_field_id, rel.parent_row_id, rel.parent_col_id, rel.parent_var_id, rel.rel_order
```

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered errors trying to open Playa fields due to the stricter group by rules (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by)

In ft.playa.php I changed line 1406 from

`GROUP BY m.member_id`

to

`GROUP BY m.member_id, m.screen_name, mg.group_title`